# operator member_function_pointer_type() without typedef?

Tags: c++, syntax, operator-overloading, typedef, pointer-to-member

Is it possible to make an `operator member_function_pointer_type()` without using typedefs (i.e. by specifying the type of the member function pointer inline)?

For example, when implementing the Safe Bool Idiom:

```
class Foo
{
    typedef void (Foo::*bool_type)() const;
public:
    operator bool_type() const;
};
```

is it possible to write out the type of `bool_type` directly when declaring the operator? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is the only case where one cannot declare a (typecasting) `operator` without using a `typedef`.

Had it been another function *name* or another `operator x`, then it works fine:

```
class Foo 
{
    typedef void (Foo::*bool_type)() const;
public:
    operator bool_type() const;

// other syntax
    void (Foo::* some_func () const) () const;  // ok! named function
    void (Foo::* operator * () const) () const;  // ok! operator *
    void (Foo::* operator () const) () const;  // error! typecasting operator
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Tu0RkJ).