# How to write a C++ conversion operator returning reference to array?

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

In C++ one can add implicit-conversion operators in a class or struct.  For instance, 3D vector types usually include something like:

```
struct Vector {
    float x, y, z;
    operator float * () { return reinterpret_cast<float *>(this); }
};
```

to allow accessing the vector's elements with subscripts, passing to functions that want a pointer, etc.  It occurred to me to wonder: can we instead write a conversion operator that returns a reference to array of float, instead of a pointer to float?

(This is of purely academic interest.  I don't know what benefits a reference-to-array would have, if any, over a simple pointer.)

As a free function we can do this like:

```
float (&convert(Vector & v))[3]
{
    return reinterpret_cast<float(&)[3]>(v);
}

Vector v;
convert(v);
```

However, I haven't been able to find the right syntax to do this as a conversion operator.  I've tried things like:

```
operator float(&)[3] ()
operator float(&())[3]
float (&operator())[3]
```

and various other permutations, but I just get various syntax errors (g++ 4.8.1).

Is it possible to write a conversion operator returning a reference to array, and if so, what is the syntax to do so?

Comment: I would imagine a typedef would work if anything.

Comment: @chris Ahh, yeah, a typedef works!  That didn't occur to me.  Still, I'd like to know if it can be done "directly".

Comment: I would be interested in seeing it done. I do recall something about a typedef/using alias being able to do things that you cannot do without it.

Comment: Does using `identity` count?

Comment: @uk4321, That's an interesting idea, but it still boils down to a type alias :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [operator member\_function\_pointer\_type() without typedef?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130368/operator-member-function-pointer-type-without-typedef)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact you can, you almost had it with the last one:

```
(&operator float())[3];
```

As for the question of whether or not a typedef is ever necessary, I think it is from reading the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6755760/2925619 (which answer is what helped me get the syntax for the above as well).

**Edit**:

Apparently, this syntax is incorrect and returning a reference to an array is forbidden as chris discovered for us. I guess you'll just have to settle for a `typedef`.

Comment: Very interesting, although the really interesting part is `error: must use a typedef to declare a conversion to 'int (&)[10]'`. Good enough for me!

Comment: @chris hmm, GCC 4.8.1 accepts it. You are using clang? Seems to be a very specific error, I think they must be right.

Comment: Yes, I do on Coliru, and that's probably what Kerrek was referring to in his answer.

Comment: @chris ha, I read the top part and didn't see the bottom half that said it was invalid. My mistake, deleting...

Comment: By all means keep it. It's a good example of how it would be done, were it not presumably explicitly forbidden (which is also a valid answer).

Comment: Interestingly enough, N3485 § 12.3.2/3 says an array isn't allowed, but not a reference to an array. On the other hand, it does list `conversion-function-id:
operator conversion-type-id`, which would, if I'm right, rule out the ampersand to the left of `operator`.

Comment: Cool!  Even if this is nonstandard, that's nice to see that g++ allows some syntax for it.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using C++11, the problem may be resolved by introducing the ref/ptr template aliases as defined below:

```
template<typename T>
using ref = T&;

template<typename T>
using ptr = T*;
```

With this aliases the declaration of reference to array conversion operator will be in form:

```
operator ref<float[3]>();
```

Also it make function taking/returning pointer to function/array declaration much cleaner, e.g.:

```
ptr<int()> foo(ptr<int(int)> bar);
```

Instead of:

```
int (*foo(int(*bar)(int)))();
```